# Rails 5 strong params with an Array within check boxes values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, strong-parameters

Given these params:

```
"product"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"",
"category_ids"=><ActionController::Parameters {"2"=>"1", "3"=>"1", "4"=>"1"} ,
"name"=>"...", "description"=>"a good prod", "size"=>"2x3m", "price"=>"23$", "url_video"=>"http://...", "remarks"=>"bla"}
```

I want to catch **category_ids** params {"2"=>"1", "3"=>"1", "4"=>"1"} with the correct `permit` and `require` syntax:

when execute

```
params.require(:product).permit(:name, :size,..., category_ids: [] )
```

the result is

```
Unpermitted parameters: id, category_ids
```

I have tried `params.require(:product).permit(:category_ids[:id,:val])`... and other variants

**what is the correct sintax?**

PD: These params are the result of , for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][2]" id="product_category_ids_2" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][3]" id="product_category_ids_3" value="1">
```

for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, autosave: true

  attr_accessor :category_list

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  before_destroy :check_products
end
```

Thanks a lot!

---

After more investigations, I found this article:

[Has Many Through Checkboxes in Rails 3.x, 4.x and 5](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3191)

Explains the good maners about this issue, and is for Rails 5, furthermore explains how `attr_accessor` is not necessary

Comment: could you post your product and category models?

Comment: Sure! I edit the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but I think you should change your checkbox to look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][]" id="product_category_ids_2" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="product[category_ids][]" id="product_category_ids_3" value="3">
```

Then in your `controller#product_params`:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:id, category_ids: [])
```

Comment: Yes! you can be sure now, that's the solution, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Basically there is no syntax to permit hash. What I usually du is having such method ApplicationController

```
def nested_params_keys(key, nested_key)
  (params[key].try(:fetch, nested_key, {}) || {}).keys
end
```

And then in other controllers I have permitted params

```
params.require(:product).permit(
  :name,
  category_ids: nested_params_keys(:product, :category_ids)
)
```