# Rails form: how to store (and retrieve) an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, forms

I'm pretty new to Rails, and want to store checkbox values from a Rails form into an array in a database field.

I'd like to do this without database relationships/join table (the form values will very rarely, if ever, change), so I'm providing the checkbox options in a hash within the form.

I've gotten something half-working, using [this answer as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231445/rails-5-form-for-with-checkbox-array).

The form displays the checkbox options, and when I update the record, it does store an array with the checked values in the database field (as a string). However, when I edit the record, the checkboxes in the form are all blank.

I believe I need to tell the form how to pre-"check" the appropriate boxes in the first parameter (:frequency, which is a text field in the database), but I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried:

1. :frequency[], and other variations
2. adding serialization in the Building model

I've seen references to using hstore in Postgres, but I'm unfamiliar with this and have not tried it.

Many thanks...

Using: Rails 6.0.2.2, Postgres 12

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_with(model: building, local: true) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:frequency, { 'Yearly': 1, 'Quarterly': 2, 'Monthly': 3, 'Weekly': 4 }, :last, :first) %>
```

`building.rb`

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord

  serialize :frequency, Array
```

`Server log` (after checking the 3rd box in form):

```
Processing by BuildingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"p2fFVpKZnw5HroZvy3qGAbguTxf+3oEOjOrhEGTu4ImS7GpVwXrcj78XPt5ENcN6GQx9K9Cn/c3ZvMwOSqVYbQ==", "building"=>{"frequency"=>["", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Update Building", "id"=>"5"}

Building Update (0.8ms)  UPDATE "buildings" SET "frequency" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "buildings"."id" = $3  [["frequency", "---\n- ''\n- '3'\n"], ["updated_at", "2020-04-05 17:56:22.142645"], ["id", 5]]
  ↳ app/controllers/buildings_controller.rb:40:in `update'
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/buildings_controller.rb:40:in `update'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/buildings/5
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms | Allocations: 6210)
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do don't use [`serialize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html). Its a dirty hack from the dark ages that stores complex types in text/varchar columns by serializing the data as JSON or YAML. It should not be used with native array/json/hstore types as the serialization is handled by the database adapter. If you use `serialize` with a array column you get something like `["[1,2,3]"]` inserted in the database, if you use it with JSON you get `"{ \"foo\":\"bar\" }"`.

Instead if you want to use an array of bitmasks just create the column as an array:

```
create_table :buildings do |t|
  t.integer 'frequency', array: true
end
```

The database adapter will automatically handle converting it to and from an array.

If you want use a HStore or JSON which both can do the job hashes do in ruby use:

```
create_table :buildings do |t|
  t.json 'frequency'
  # or
  t.hstore 'frequency'
end
```

But IMHO I would just get with the program and create a join table. This is not worth the fuss and crappy resulting queries / issues that joins can solve. ActiveRecord was built around tables and the relational model. Not hstore/array/json columns.

```
class Frequency
  has_many :building_frequencies
  has_many :frequencies, through: :building_frequencies
end

class BuildingFrequency
  belongs_to :building
  belongs_to :frequency
end

class Building
  has_many :building_frequencies
  has_many :frequencies, through: :building_frequencies
end
```

---

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:frequency_ids, Frequency.all, :id, :name) %>
```

---

```
def building_params
  params.require(:building)
        .permit(
          :foo, :bar,
          frequency_ids: []
        )
end
```

It gets the job done, gives you referential integrity and lets you use inner joins to filter rows on the frequency which is actually much more efficient then poking inside an array/hstore.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed and clear answer! I talked it through with a mentor and he essentially said the same thing—but it's super helpful to see a few examples of how it *could* be done. He scared me with "what if" data integrity issues too :)

Comment: You might want to read [PostgreSQL anti-patterns: Unnecessary json/hstore dynamic columns](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/). It applies to array columns also to a lesser degree.